# Stop script in MySQL Workbench after error

Tags: mysql-workbench

I just ran a script in MySQL Workbench 6.3 Community.
I've set it to 'Stop Script Execution on Errors'.

There were two queries that gave errors.
The errors say 'Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.'
Ok, so I missed that. No big deal.

But after that, the script simply continued as if there were no error at all, or as if I never set 'Stop Script Execution on Errors'.
As a consequence I've lost some data. (This was a test database, so no worries there.)

The script continues after the errors:

[image]

Any idea how to make it stop executing the script?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague pointed me to Edit->Preferences, SQL Editor, SQL Execution, Continue SQL script execution on errors (by default).

[Continue SQL script execution on errors (by default)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M83P.png)

This worked after restarting Workbench.